# Обязательны ли указатели при реализации бинарного дерева в pascal?

Tags: pascal, указатели, структуры-данных

Я создал 2 структуры данных: Дерево и циклический список. Написал их на Java. Затем перенес в Pascal. В java нет указателей. Есть лишь разделение на примитивы(int, double) и обьектные типы. Все примитивы хранятся в стеке. А обьекты в куче. В паскале я слаб. Но я как-то умудрился все сделать без использования указателей( в паскале это оператор ^).

Вот теперь не пойму верно ли я все сделал?
https://pastebin.com/NteFNXtQ

```
// класс описывающий узел дерева
type
Node = class
public
  key:integer; // ключ, по которому производится поиск
  data:double; // данные в узле дерева
  left,right,parent: Node; // 3 указателя - на левого и правого ребенка узла
  // а также указатель на родителя узла
end;

// класс двоичное дерево
type
BinaryTreeClass = class
public
  root, currentElement : Node; // 2 указателя - на корень дерева и на текущий элемент
  size : integer; // размер дерева - суммарное кол-во всех узлов
end;
```

Comment: Скорее всего, указатели здесь используются неявно, как и в Java.

Comment: На обычном паскале такое не компилируется: https://ideone.com/v9h76T

Comment: @Qwertiy Изначально в вопросе была ссылка на pastebin. Так вот, тот код и на Delphi не скомпилируется

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Утверждение, что в Java нет указателей в корне неверно. Как раз наоборот - в Java все объекты являются указателями
2. В Паскале не было классов (в Turbo Pascal 5.5 появились объекты но они обозначали особые структуры - они были идентичны понятию класса, но их экземпляры хранились на стеке)
3. Вы используете `class`, это значит что Вы используете Delphi или какой-то клон паскаля

Так вот, в Delphi экземпляры классов, также как и в Java, являются указателями, при этом операция разыменования `^` для них неопределена и приводит к ошибке компиляции

Comment: Объекты в Turbo Pascal появились, начиная с версии 5.5

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Спасибо за уточнение